# ng-include gives err_content_decoding_failed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have a simple ng-include that shows some html code. But in chrome, quite often I get the following error:

> GET https://example.com/view.html net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

I tried turning gzip compression off by adding `<urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false"/>` in my web.config, but it didn't work.

```
<ng-include src="'view.html'"></ng-include>
```

view.html:

```
<section ng-show="vm.showInclude">
    <h2 class="text-center">
        Hello world
    </h2>
</section>
```

Anyone has any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: seems like your HTML file is the issue. You can try a workaround by adding html script with `<script type="text/ng-template" id="view.html"> ... </script>` in your [main page](https://plnkr.co/edit/ELvhcrVlv1ENjyzZuXAe?p=preview) (index.html)

Comment: Now I posted a smaller version of my html file, but its basically some divs with text and some angular stuff, nothing fancy. Is it possible to see whats wrong with the html?

Comment: When I take the html file and copy paste it into the main file it works fine, but just not with ng-include